# Building a buffer over a terrain model

Tags: mapping, gis

I have a polygon and a terrain model (can be either grid or TIN).  I'd like to a build, say, a 1km buffer so that the 1km is measured over the surface of the terrain, i.e. not planimetric.   The buffer must always be at least 1km from the polygon and prefer a measure over the flattest part of the terrain.

Anyone know a good way to do this that is robust for all the edge cases you get with real terrain?

An algorithm or solution using FOSS tools is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Grass Gis it's  posible look  this link

http://grass.ibiblio.org/gdp/html_grass62/r.buffer.html

or with pgraster

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRasterTutorial01

http://cartosig.upv.es/es/system/files/jomarlla/PGRASTER_20070710-0001.pdf

good luck